# Swing remove JTexField and JLabel

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtextfield, jcheckbox

I have a `JTable` 2 columns, column name and check-box. If the user clicks the check box next to the name of the column that creates a new field for data entry. I wish the unclick check box input field has disappeared.

How can I do that?

[image]

My code to add a new field:

```
 headerTable.getModel().addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() {

                @Override
                public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
                    if(e.getColumn() >= 0  && e.getFirstRow()>-1){
                        int id =  e.getFirstRow();
                        String colName = (String)headerTable.getValueAt(e.getFirstRow(), 1);
                        boolean colValue = (boolean)headerTable.getValueAt(e.getFirstRow(), 2);

                        System.out.println("Row : " + e.getFirstRow() +
                                   " value :" + headerTable.getValueAt(e.getFirstRow(), 2));
                        appListener.getColumnId(id);
                        //create texfield
                        if(colValue==false){
                            System.out.println("Delete");
                        }                         
                        jTextField = new JTextField(20);
                        textField.put(id,jTextField);
                        if (textField != null && !textField.isEmpty()) {
                            textField.get(textField.size()-1);
                            System.out.println("Add");
                        }
                        JLabel kolor1name = new JLabel(colName+": ");
                        operationContent.add(kolor1name,"");
                        operationContent.add(jTextField, "growy, wrap");

                        revalidate();
                        repaint();
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: do you want to remove check box when you click on it??

Comment: he wants to remove the input mask (4 textfields) when he unchecks the checkbox i think

Comment: After selecting the checkbox field appears afte unclick checkbox field disappears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a **Vector** of all the fields that you want. And when the user clicks on the check-box, you can add it to the Vector. for eg:

```
Vector fields = new Vector();
```

And when you get the notification, you add the name of the field in the vector, and call the **refreshPanel()** method, which removes all the fields in it, and add the new fields to it.

```
// In the tableChanged(...) method
fields.addElement(colname);
refreshPanel();
```

Then the **refreshPanel()** method:

```
public void refreshPanel()
{
     String fNames[] = (String[]) fields.toArray();
     panel.removeAll();
     for(String fname : fNames)
     {
          //add the fields in `newPanel`, the field name is in `fname` variable
     }
     revalidate();
     repaint();
}
```

And when the user deselects the check-box, then remove the field name from the Vector:

```
fields.removeElement(colname);
refreshPanel();
```

Answer (score 1):

Quick-n-dirty way:

```
if(colValue){
    jTextField = new JTextField(20);

    textField.put(id,jTextField);

    if (textField != null && !textField.isEmpty()) {
        textField.get(textField.size()-1);
        System.out.println("Add");
    }

    JLabel kolor1name = new JLabel(colName+": ");
    operationContent.add(kolor1name,"");
    operationContent.add(jTextField, "growy, wrap");

} else {                         
    System.out.println("Delete");
    Component[] comps = operationContent.getComponents();
    operationContent.remove(comps[comps.length - 2]);
    operationContent.remove(comps[comps.length - 1]);
}
revalidate();
repaint();
```

But this way may (not always) cause layouting issues (panel looks bad after removal).

Better way: provide full relayout of the panel "operationContent"

```
operationContent.removeAll();
// add all the components above the kolor1name
if(colValue){
    jTextField = new JTextField(20);

    textField.put(id,jTextField);

    if (textField != null && !textField.isEmpty()) {
        textField.get(textField.size()-1);
        System.out.println("Add");
    }

    JLabel kolor1name = new JLabel(colName+": ");
    operationContent.add(kolor1name,"");
    operationContent.add(jTextField, "growy, wrap");
}
revalidate()
repaint();
```

This way is ok, but in some cases can also provide layouting issues. But if you want to add more than 1 row (for example when user select 2 checkboxes in table) it's colud be the best way for you.

Another way: use the [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html). This only will work when you always add one field (with label) independed on how many comboboxes in the table was selected.

Comment: The display is ok, but it always removes the last element that is on the list, but not always the case though. For example. Will I choose the second element, third, and fifth then unclick the second, and the list clears my fifth and not second.

Comment: @user3193748 try the second way. simply remove all the fields an provide a complete relayouting depending on the selected checks.